# Add promoted actions at the end

Tags: 2013, delegate-control

I am overriding `PromotedActions` and am adding a few custom links to it.

The problem is, despite of setting the sequence number to 1000000, the links are still coming at the beginning.

How can I make then come at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your master page, you need to change PromotedAction delegate control order, something link below code:

1. SharePoint:SPSharePromotedActionButton runat="server"
2. SharePoint:SPSyncPromotedActionButton runat="server"
3. SharePoint:PageStateActionButton id="PageStateActionButton" runat="server" Visible="false"
4. SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PromotedActions" AllowMultipleControls="true"

Observe the order.